# How to convert an array of integers into x/y coordinates for rickshaw

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, hash, rickshaw

I'm trying to integrate the awesome JS graphing library Rickshaw into my project. 
Rickshaw can be found here: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/

The data that I want to graph is in a simple array:

```
data = [51929, 65932, 49119, 50379, 103501, 92430, 93107, 105710, 115200, 109283]
```

I would like to use the index of each element in the array as the x coordinate, and the element itself as the y coordinate. I need to format this into something like the following format so Richshaw can do its magic:

```
data = [ { x: 0, y: 40 }, { x: 1, y: 49 }, { x: 2, y: 17 }, { x: 3, y: 42 } ];
```

I've tried various methods, the closest I have come is to produce an array of quotes with the hashes inside, like so:

```
clean_data = []
data.each_with_index do |value, index|
  clean_data << "{x: #{index}, y: #{value} }”
end 
clean_data.to_a
```

which returns:

```
["{x: 0, y: 51929}", "{x: 1, y: 65932}", "{x: 2, y: 49119}" ... etc...]
```

So my question is either, how can I remove the quotes in the above to get just an array of hashes, or, if I'm on the wrong track: how can I format the array to make it presentable to Rickshaw? I'd prefer to work with Ruby here, but anything in JavaScript would be great as well.

Thanks.

Comment: So far none of the answers are working, Rickshaw doesn't seem to work well with the hash rocket. I did a number of find-and-replace in sublime to get rid of the rockets and put the colon on the right side of the variables and that worked, so I know it's not Rickshaw's fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. Try this:

```
data = [51929, 65932, 49119, 50379, 103501, 92430, 93107, 105710, 115200, 109283]
clean_data = []
data.each_with_index do |value, index|
  clean_data << {:x => index, :y => value}
end 

clean_data.to_json
```

Comment: Rickshaw doesn't seem to like the resulting json string. I'm wondering if I'm just going to have to do some regex magic to get it in that specific format. Seems like there has to be a way though...

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because I think it was very close and may actually be the same thing as what I finally ended up doing after I got some help. What finally did it was, after processing the array and converting it to a JSON string, I inserted it into Rickshaw using embedded ruby and raw to  handle the escaped characters: <%= raw(@data) %>. This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
p data.map.with_index{|val, idx|
  Hash[:x,idx,:y,val]
}
#=> [{:x=>0, :y=>51929}, {:x=>1, :y=>65932}, {:x=>2, :y=>49119} .....
```